# Estimated proof size less than measured

Tags: weight, benchmarking

I was running some benchmark, and noticed that the estimated proof size was less than the measured size, despite `MaxEncodedLen` being used in this crate. The estimation of 0 is clearly wrong, but this is the one that gets used in `Weight::from_parts`. My first guess was that `MaxEncodedLen` was perhaps implemented incorrectly, but they're all auto-derived so I don't think that can be the case. I also tried inspecting the `max_encoded_len()` of of the key type, and it was non-zero. What can cause this behavior?

```
/// Storage: VaultRegistry MinimumCollateralVault (r:0 w:1)
/// Proof: VaultRegistry MinimumCollateralVault (max_values: None, max_size: Some(43), added: 2518, mode: MaxEncodedLen)
fn set_minimum_collateral() -> Weight {
    // Proof Size summary in bytes:
    //  Measured:  `711`
    //  Estimated: `0`
    // Minimum execution time: 9_105_000 picoseconds.
    Weight::from_parts(9_553_000, 0)
        .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().writes(1_u64))
}
```

Comment: Take a look into the pallet template as an example of the benchmarking function: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs .It would be great if you can share more code to try to replicate and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments shows that `MinimumCollateralVault` was not read - therefore it should not be in the proof.
The problem here is actually that the `Measured` is wrong. The estimated Proof size of zero is correct.

This was fixed in [#13485](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13485). Please try to update your Substrate version.
In any case; thanks for letting us know, only like this can we improve! When you are sure that there is a bug, you can better open an issue in [GitHub directly](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/new/choose).